# Can Bran see the current past?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

We know Bran from The *Game of Thrones* can see the past, but can he also see things that happened *after* he became the Three-Eyed Raven?  Can he see current events without warging?

An example would be: Can Bran/Raven know that Jon betrayed Dany by telling the Stark kids about his Targaryen ancestry. Could he have spied on that Conversation Dany and Jon had?

Comment: Why not? If he can see the future then why not far present? Also, he can wrag in birds too to see stuff.

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted, it seems like a reasonable question. I don't think we've seen any unambiguous examples of Bran doing the seeing-the-past weirwood trick to observe something that happened in the past but after he gained these abilities.

Comment: Given that he was there when Jon told Sansa and Arya about his ancestry, and he's not blind nor deaf, I would assume that he knows Jon did.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think you should re-read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes.

In S07E07, Samwell Tarly and Bran have [this conversation](https://youtu.be/rnp5DuSIMhc?t=47):

> SAMWELL: What happened to you beyond the Wall?
>
> BRAN: I became the Three-Eyed Raven.
>
> SAMWELL: Oh! I don't know what that means.
>
> BRAN: I can see things that happened in the past. **I can see things happening now, all over the world.**

I don't know if "now" means things literally happening right now, or things that have just happened, but he can see things that happened after he became the Three-Eyed Raven.

Answer (score -1):

> Could he have spied on that Conversation Dany and Jon had?

As for spying (without looking in the past or future), I guess he could just to move in Dany's dragon and listen to them...

Comment: There is no proof at allhe can warg into a Dragon